# CARBON cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java in macOS Catalina

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am running the WSO2IS source code in eclipse by using maven.
INFO  [org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions.servers.carbonserver.CarbonServerManager] - Starting carbon server.............
INFO  [org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions.servers.utils.ServerLogReader] - Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
INFO  [org.wso2.carbon.automation.extensions.servers.utils.ServerLogReader] -  CARBON cannot execute /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/bin/java

it appears the error which due to JAVA_HOME not found.

However, I already configured JAVA_HOME in the .bash_profile, and it's sourced properly.
[JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqwaZ.png)

I notice the error is due to eclipse attempts to execute wso2server.sh under root user, and JAVA_HOME cannot found in root users.

I have done the following resolutions, but all fail. please kindly help

S1: add JAVA_HOME into root user account .profile / .bash_profile / .bashrc, but after login root user again, MacOS cannot read JAVA_HOME at all.
S2: try to create a soft link to link the WSO2 default java folder to the desire one. but MacOS does not give the permission to change anything under JavaVM.framework
S3: try to find where generates wso2server.sh and attempt to amend wso2server.sh with the proper default JAVA_HOME string. but not able to find anywhere from the source code.

Appreciate you guys' help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Change the JAVA_HOME value in line 52 wso2server.sh

`#JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/${JAVA_VERSION}/Home

JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home`